# Force a View to redraw itself

Tags: java, android

I have created a custom View (let's call it `MyView`) which basically just draws some text on itself using the canvas. The text to be drawn is set using a global variable.

At some point during the program's execution, I want to change the global variable, and have the `MyView` redraw itself to update the text. I tried `findViewById()` and then `invalidate()`, but this does nothing. I suspect that since nothing within the `MyView` has changed, it thinks it has no reason to call `onDraw()`. Is there any way to force a View to redraw itself even if it thinks it doesn't need to?

Comment: I answered the same question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56140050/6884103

Answer (score 60, accepted):

> If I have a member variable inside the MyView that stores the text, and create a public setter for it, then just calling that method causes the MyView to redraw itself

Setting a variable inside the `View` will not invoke a draw on the View. In fact, neither does  the view system know nor care about internal variables.

Invoking `invalidate()` on a View causes it to draw itself via the View. You should check this out: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html.

A `TextView` internally invalidates itself when you invoke `setText()` and redraws itself with the new text set via the `setText()` call. You should also do something similar.

Comment: Sorry, you are right, I did indeed call `invalidate()`. I meant to say that calling `invalidate()` didn't work because the variable I was changing was external to the `View` (it was global). So I created an internal variable and changed that before invalidating.

Answer (score 2):

Okay so I figured it out. If I have a member variable inside the `MyView` that stores the text, and create a public setter for it, then just calling that method causes the `MyView` to redraw itself. Simple!

Answer (score 2):

Example:

```
customView.set(...)
customView.requestLayout();
customView.invalidate();
```

Reference: android.widget.TextView#onConfigurationChanged

```
@Override
protected void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    if (!mLocalesChanged) {
        mTextPaint.setTextLocales(LocaleList.getDefault());
        if (mLayout != null) {
            nullLayouts();
            requestLayout();
            invalidate();
        }
    }
    if (mFontWeightAdjustment != newConfig.fontWeightAdjustment) {
        mFontWeightAdjustment = newConfig.fontWeightAdjustment;
        setTypeface(getTypeface());
    }
}
```